# How to make an array of alphabets from a file and update in a new file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a single column file.

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
D
```

I want to use this file and want to make a new one as below

```
command="A" "B" "C" "D"
TYPE=1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4,
```

These A B C D are random alphabets and varies file to file.

I tried to overcome the solution with below shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
NQ=$(cat RLP.txt | wc -l)
ELEMENT='element='
echo "$ELEMENT" > element.txt
TYPE='types='
echo "$TYPE" > types.txt
for i in `seq 1 1 $NQ`
do
RLP=$(echo "$i" | tail -n 1)
cat RLP.txt | head -n "$RLP" | tail -n 1 > el.$RLP.txt

done
paste element.txt el.*.txt
paste types.txt
```

The output of `paste element.txt el.*.txt` is `element= A A A B B B C C D`
I could not remove the repeated alphabets and  put the reaming  alphabets in "".
and cold not move forward for with second command to get

```
TYPE=1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4,
```

which represents that the 1st alphabets repeated three times, 2nd alphabets repeated three times, 3rd  alphabets repeated two times and so on..

Comment: I am updating the question.

Comment: Dear Sir, I have updated my attempts

Comment: FYI the word is `letters`, not `alphabets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
!seen[$1]++ {
    cmd = cmd sep "\"" $1 "\""
    cnt++
}
{
    type = type sep cnt
    sep = OFS
}
END {
    print "command=" cmd
    print "TYPE=" type ","
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
command="A" "B" "C" "D"
TYPE=1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4,
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple text processing tools in a pipeline, this can be achieved by one `awk` command as below

```
awk '
{
    unique[$0]
}

prev !~ $0 {
    alpha[NR] = idx++
}

{
    prev = $0
    alpha[NR] = idx
}

END {
    for (i in unique) {
        str = str ? (str " " "\"" i "\"") : "\"" i "\""
    }
    first = "command=" str
    str = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
        str = str ? (str " " alpha[i]) : alpha[i]
    }
    second = "TYPE=" str ","
    print(first "\n" second) > "types.txt"
    close("types.txt")
}' RLP.txt
```

The command works as follows

- Each unique line in the file is saved as an index in into the array `unique`
- The array `alpha` keeps track of the unique value counter, i.e. every time a value in the file changes, the counter is incremented at the corresponding line number `NR`
- The `END` block is all about constructing the output from the array to a string value and writing the result to the new file "types.txt"

Comment: Thank you sir. This gives me element="A             " "B             " "C            " "D" .        Can we delete the extra space keeping a single space and add one comma at the  end of line TYPE=1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4?

Comment: @astha: It does not add an extra space as you claim. I've tested the solution before posting it. Do run the command exactly as I've posted. Also add the requirement about adding comma to the question

Comment: my bad. I have spaces in my file.It is working well. Thank you for the script and for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) implementation.  Requires at least Bash version 4 for the associative array

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile="./RLP.txt"
infile="./infile"
declare -A map

while read line; do
 (( map["$line"]++ ))
done < "$infile"

command="command="
command+=$(printf "\"%s\" " "${!map[@]}")

type="$(
  for i in "${map[@]}"; do
    ((k++))
    for (( j=0; j < i; j++ )); do
      printf " %d" "$k"
    done
  done
),"
echo "$command" >> "$outfile"
echo "TYPE=${type#* }" >> "$outfile"
```

Comment: That would be orders of magnitude slower than an awk implementation and would fail given some input values (eg. it'd convert `\t` to a literal tab character). See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @EdMorton [tag:awk] is life